# Building msi with cx_Freeze : ValueError: FCI error 1

Tags: python, pygame, cx-freeze

I want to make a msi for my **PyGame** game with **cx_Freeze** :

(I already created an execute file)

So, i used `python setup.py bdist_msi`, but I got this message :

`File "C:\Python34\lib\msilib\__init__.py", line 213, in commit
    FCICreate(filename, self.files)
ValueError: FCI error 1`

An idea ?

Answer (score 0):

I had that problem, the build was created and worked ok, but an ValueError: FCI error 1 take place in the msi creation. In my case, it was due to data files containing a point in your name (example AB_12345.1.fasta). I replaced the point by the underscore symbol (example AB_12345_1.fasta) and everything worked properly. I hope it helps you on something.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I used non-ascii characters at the path contains. I solved that by changing the path contains into ascii characters.

Comment: How is this any different from py.cs's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43314095/369450)?

Comment: Thanks, this helped me figure out my problem resulted from a German Umlaut in a file name. (I also had to remove the build directory after I noticed that).

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem installing 6º version of the cx_Freeze. In terminal, do:

```
python -m pip install cx_Freeze==6.0b1
```

Worked for me, hope to help you.

OBS: `python -m pip install cx_Freeze --upgrade` doesn't upgrade from version 5 to 6.

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem. I solved my problem by deleting the build directory. 
Then run `python setup.py bdist_msi`.
That works for me.
I wish it will help you.